# Modifications and dilatations for stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-stacks

In the paper "Algebraization of formal moduli II" Artin proves the existence of "modification" and "dilatation". Are these opertaions valid on algebraic stacks??

I am attaching the particular page in the paper. The definitions are in the first page itself.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was too long for a comment.

The main theorem of Artin's paper applies for Deligne-Mumford stacks of finite type over a field or over an excellent Dedekind domain $S$: for a finite type Deligne-Mumford stack $X'$ over $S$ (with separated and finite type diagonal), for a $1$-morphism $Y'\hookrightarrow X'$ that is representable by closed immersions, for a $1$-morphism $f_Y:Y'\to Y$ to a finite type, Deligne-Mumford $S$-stack $Y$ such that $f_Y$ is representable by proper morphisms, for the associated "formal completion" $\mathcal{X}'$ of $X'$ along $Y'$ (if memory serves, Iwanari was going to work out the theory of formal stacks), for a formal dilatation $\mathfrak{f}:\mathfrak{X}'\to \mathfrak{X}$ reducing to $f_Y$, there exists a unique dilatation of stacks $f:X'\to X$ fitting into the commutative diagram.

The point is, you can reduce this to Artin's theorem for algebraic <del>stacks</del> spaces using étale covers.  Using facts about coarse moduli spaces and the local theory of Deligne-Mumford stacks, for every geometric point of $Y'$, there exists a $1$-morphism from an algebraic space $\widetilde{Y}\to Y$ that is representable by étale morphisms and whose image contains the geometric point, and there exists a $1$-morphism from an algebraic space $\widetilde{X}'\to X'$ that is representable by étale morphisms and that restricts over $Y'$ to the $2$-fiber product $\widetilde{Y}'=\widetilde{Y}\times_Y Y'$.  So now you can pullback the formal dilatation to the formal neighborhood of $\widetilde{Y}'$ in $\widetilde{X}'$.  Apply Artin's theorem to get $\widetilde{f}:\widetilde{X}'\to \widetilde{X}$.  Finally use the uniqueness in Artin's theorem to prove the descent condition to construct a $1$-morphism $f:X'\to X$.

I do not see how to make this argument work for algebraic stacks, precisely because it is difficult to arrange a compatible "atlas" of the stack $Y$ and the stack $X'$.  Perhaps an expert on stacks can say whether this is known (I am a little skeptical).

Comment: @potentiallydense.  Yes!  Sorry for the typo.  I will correct it now.